# How do I find the last position of a comma in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie and trying to find the last position of a comma in a string. I'd like to use a while loop as shown below in my code. I get really frustrated when I code sometimes because I seem to struggle with easy logic. Anyways, here is my code:

```
# Find last occurrence of the comma
    while True:
        commaPos = newNameStr.find(",", 0)
        if commaPos == -1:
            return the commaPos before
```

Am I on the right track? I took a Python course from Udacity and we had a similar problem and they solved it like this but I forgot how they wrote the code.

Comment: use str.rfind(",")

Comment: Ok thank you but how would I solve without rfind?

Comment: use loop from end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are giving the argument zero to `commaPos = newNameStr.find(",", 0)` it will only ever give the first comma which will result in an infinite loop. Try this `commaPos = newNameStr.find(",", commaPos)` and make sure to initialize `commaPos` to 0

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm still unsure how to complete the while loop. Especially where I have my 'return' statement. My original thought was to stop the loop when find returns -1 and get the position before but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: This will return -1 for any string that has other characters following the last comma.  You need to keep the result of `find()` in a separate variable, and only assign that to `commaPos` if it is not -1.

Comment: @johnnewbie25 the logic is fine, you will also need to store the results of the previous comma position however, you can do this by setting the `oldCommaPos = CommaPos` before calling find. Other than that the logic will work, the only issue you would have is if there is no comma, you will get zero which would be equivalent to it being in the first string position, make sure to account for this

Comment: Ok thank you very much